# error msg when open linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, python, virtualenv

I installed a virtualenv in the other day using pip and its not working properly, also when i start the terminal it opens whit that msg on the top

```
>     bash: /usr/bin/python: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
>     virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.
> 
>     If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
>     check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
>     VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
>     set properly.
```

i did some research and still could fix it, i'm new at linux.
thanks all

Comment: You need to search for the location for "virtualenvwrapper.sh".  It might be in "/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh".. it might be in "~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh".. use the `find` command if you need to.  Then set the `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` environment variable to that path.  If you need more help after locating this file, update your question. :)

Comment: Thanks by the answer
i did the search and didn't find this file, i founded the virtualenv one not this one i think its not exists

Comment: Try this:  `sudo pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper` .. then `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper`.. then to make sure you have it, `find / -name virtualenvwrapper.sh` ..